# Use session with NSURLSession and WKWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, nsurlsession, wkwebview

In my app, I want to do login using webview and then all further request to server is done using `NSURLSession`.

I'm able to perform successful login using `WKWebView`. On it's success I get session information. I had implemented it previously using `UIWebView` and it was working properly. All my further web service call were working fine with NSURLSession. That is, session information were being passed along with request

Now when I implemented login with `WKWebView` and I'm trying to call service using NSURLSession, it's not giving me proper response as session information are not being passed.

Is there any way, I can store those session information and use it with `NSURLSession`

Any help will be appreciated. Please help!

Comment: Hey @ankita-shah , have you been able to solve the issue you describe? My situation is the opposite of yours. I'm using URLSession to get some cookies, and then using it in a WKWebView.